# Spark job is getting stuck with connection manager issue

Tags: apache-spark

My app gets stuck with this message..

`14/09/10 18:11:45 INFO ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal/10.33.139.85]
14/09/10 18:11:46 INFO SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [ip-1xx-xx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal/10.33.139.85:44309]
14/09/10 18:11:46 INFO SendingConnection: Connected to [ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal/10.33.139.85:44309], 1 messages pending`

I'm executing this on EMR cluster as a step.

Spark version : 1.0.1 [Hadoop 2.2]

Kindly request some suggestions ....

Comment: How are you executing your job? Using spark-submit? Can you post the command you use?

Comment: im executing on EMR cluster as a step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question...

This was because underlying data was heavily skewed , one node getting all the data and it was not able to process...memory was close to 100% and it would have failed had I waited for few more minutes...

I could resolve this by introduce an additional random number based key in join conditions...

Example :

```
import scala.util.Random

case class dimension(key: Int, id: Int, start_date: Int, end_date: Int,skew_mp: Int)

val sequenceNumberTableForSkewJoin = sc.parallelize(0 to 199)

sequenceNumberTableForSkewJoin.map { row => skw(row.toInt) }.registerAsTable("skw")

sc.textFile("S3Pathtoreadthedimension").cartesian(sequenceNumberTableForSkewJoin).map {  case(row,skew) =>
  val parts = row.split("\t")
  dimension(parts(6).toInt, parts(0).toInt, parts(7).toInt, parts(8).toInt,skew)
}.registerAsTable("dimension")

case class fact(dim_key1: Int,
  dim_key2: String,
  skew_resolver: Int,
  measures: Double)

sc.textFile("S3PathtoReadFactTable").map { row =>
     val parts = row.split("\t")
      fact(parts(0).toInt,
        parts(1),
        Random.nextInt(200),
        measures
    }.registerAsTable("fact")

sqlContext.sql("select * from dimension,fact where dimension.key=fact.dim_key1 and dimension.skew=fact.skew_resolver").saveAsTextFile("outputpath")
```

Thanks